# Why does cypress only loop through once inside the for loop

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress, cypress-each

Why does cypress only loop through once inside the for loop?

Test code is this:

```js
cy.get('body').contains('Automation').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.get('body').contains('Automation').parents()
    .eq(1)
    .find('mfc-dropdown > div > mfc-button > button', { timeout: 6000 })
    .first()
    .click({ force: true });
  cy.get(this.DELETE_FILE_BUTTON).click();
  cy.get('.mfc-dialog-container')
    .find(this.CONFIRM_DELETE)
    .click({ force: true });
});
```

Comment: You need to format your code correctly

Comment: How many elements with `Automation` text do you have in your webpage?

Answer (score 5):

@JessefSpecialisterren has given the right reason why no looping occurs.

What can you do about it?

You can move the `contains` inside the `get()` using the [:contains() pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

> Description: Select **all elements** that contain the specified text.

```js
cy.get(':contains(Automation)').each(($el, index) => {
```

You really want to target the element directly, not the `<body>` element

For example

```js
cy.get('button:contains(Automation)').each(($el, index) => {
```

---

What about lines 2-3?

That looks dubious, I think you want

```js
cy.get('button:contains(Automation)').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el).parents().eq(1)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Because you're looping over the result of the `contains` command, and `contains` only returns the *first* matching element, not *all* matching elements. See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Single-Element

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't looping through all items, but rather only looking at the first one by saying

```
cy.get().contains()
```

I needed to loop through the whole list by doing

```
cy.get('button:contains('Automation'))
```